# Unable to uninstall patch using wusa.exe using /quiet switch

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

Has anybody tried uninstalling the patch wusa.exe /quiet switch in windows 10 redstone?

Seems it was not accepting the quiet switch.

The below command i used to uninstall the patch:

Wusa.exe /uninstall /kb:xxxxx /quiet /norestart

Any ideas?

Comment: what is not working? Some patches are permanent and can't be removed.

Comment: Recent april month security patch  KB4015217? We identified some issue with this patch in our environment and trying to remove that patch but it is not working with /quiet switch.

Comment: have you tried via control panel?

Comment: it will work without quiet and from control panel also . But i am trying to automate this task with powershell for mass deployment .

Comment: It will work like this wusa.exe /uninstall /KB:4015217 /norestart but it won't work with /quiet switch(wusa.exe /uninstall /KB:4015217 /quiet /norestart).

Comment: ok, so use it without quiet switch

Comment: without quiet switch , it will popup to user yes or no message box to uninstall the patch. i am looking for silent uninstall.

Comment: I think you will need to use `dism` instead.  Perhaps you could close this question and then ask again on Server Fault, so I can post a more detailed answer?

Comment: Try `dism /online /Remove-Package /PackageName:Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~14393.1066.1.8 /Quiet /NoRestart`

Answer (score 0):

This happens also in Windows Server 2016, the /quiet option cannot be use in combination with /kb:xxxx

You may use the below:

```
$SearchUpdates = dism /online /get-packages | findstr "Package_for"
$updates = $SearchUpdates.replace("Package Identity : ", "") | findstr "KBXXXXXX"
DISM.exe /Online /Remove-Package /PackageName:$updates /quiet /norestart
```

[Check this other SO thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/111525/how-do-to-uninstall-windows-updates-from-a-prompt-or-ps-in-hyper-v-server/869076#869076)